# How to pass a view and a json from a function in laravel?

Tags: ajax, json, laravel, laravel-4

This is my function

```
    if(isset($_POST['franchisesIds'])) {
        $id_array = array();
        foreach($_POST['franchisesIds'] as $data) {
            array_push($id_array, (int)$data['id']);
        }
        $results = DB::table('franchises')->whereIn('id', $id_array)->get();

    }
    return Response::json(array($id_array));
    return View::make('frontend.stores')->with('franchisesAll', $results);
```

So I am a little bit confused on how to pass all this data. I need to pass the json just to make sure everything worked. And at the same time I need to pass a list of ids to the view.
How can I do this??

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this is what you wanted : 
Please don't use directly $_POST or $_GET [instead use Input](http://laravel.com/docs/requests)

```
   $franchisesIds = Input::get('franchisesIds');
   $id_array = array();

    if($franchisesIds) {

        foreach( $franchisesIds as $data) {
            array_push($id_array, (int)$data['id']);
        }

        $results = DB::table('franchises')->whereIn('id', $id_array)->get();

    }

     $jsonArray = json_encode($id_array);

    return View::make('frontend.stores')->with(array('franchisesAll'=>$results,'idArrays'=>$jsonArray));
```

In order to pass multiple values to the view,  please read more about it in [the official Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use `Input::get('franchisesIds')` instead of `$_POST['franchisesIds']`, also there is no reason to do this `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($_POST['franchisesIds'] as $data) {
    array_push($id_array, (int)$data['id']);
}
```

Because this is already an array and you are bulding another array from this array, makes no sense. So you may try this instead:

```
if($franchisesIds = Input::get('franchisesIds')) {
    $franchises = DB::table('franchises')->whereIn('id', $franchisesIds)->get();
}
```

Then to pass both `$franchisesIds` and `result` to your `view` you may use this:

```
return View::make('frontend.stores')
            ->with('franchises', $franchises)
            ->with('franchisesIds', $franchisesIds);
```

You can also use something like this ([compact](https://www.php.net/compact)):

```
return View::make('frontend.stores', compact('franchises', 'franchisesIds'));
```

There is no reason to use `json_encode` to encode your `$franchisesIds`.

Comment: Thank you it does make sense. Tho still doesn't work. I still get the 500 error if I don't pass the json

Comment: What you are doing with the `$franchisesIds` in your view, you need it be an array as it is now.

Comment: Is this related with `ajax` ?

Comment: No, the Ids are only to get the franchises, that's it. And the franchises I need to return them to the view. But sems like if I don't do it I keep getting POST http://localhost/appleautoglass/public/front/getSelectedLocations 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: `json_encode($franchisesIds)` will convert your `$franchisesIds` array into `json string` and you have to `decode` it if you want to use it in your `view`, if you are sending the `$franchisesIds` to client/browser then you need to encode it.

Comment: Are you sure you have used right `variable` names because it doesn't make any sense to produce a `500` error, how can you use `$franchisesIds` in your view if encoded to `json string` ?

Comment: Did you copy pasted my code, if so then there was a `typo` in my code and I fixed it now.

Comment: Actually `Input::get(''franchisesIds)` should be `Input::get('franchisesIds')`, it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
$results = DB::table('franchises')
    ->whereIn('id', $id_array)
    ->get()
    ->toJson();
```